# Regex for old type of comment

Tags: regex, sed, grep

I have this kind of comments (a few examples):

1. ```
   //========================================================================
   // some text some text some text some text some text some text some text
   ```
2. ```
   //========================================================================
   // some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text
   // some text some text
   // (..)
   ```

I want to replace it with comment of this style:

```
/*****************************************************************************\

Description:

    some text some text
    some text some text some text

\*****************************************************************************/
```

So I need regular expression for this. I managed to make this regex:

```
//=+\r//(.+)+
```

It matches the comment in group, but only one line(example 1). How to make it work with many lines comments(like example 2)?

Thanks for help

Comment: May be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152708/how-can-i-search-for-a-multiline-pattern-in-a-file-use-pcregrep

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507684/convert-single-line-comments-to-block-comments

Answer (score 1):

Using sed:

```
sed -n '
  \_^//==*_!p;
  \_^//==*_{
    s_//_/*_; s_=_\*_g; s_\*$_\*\\_;
    h; p; i\
Desctiption:
    : l; n; \_//[^=]_{s_//_\t_;p;};t l;
    x;s_^/_\\_;s_\\$_/_;p;x;p;
  }
  ' input_file
```

Commented version:

```
sed -n '
  # just print non comment lines
  \_^//==*_!p;
  # for old-style block comments:
  \_^//==*_{
    # generate header line
    s_//_/*_; s_=_\*_g; s_\*$_\*\\_;
    # remember header, add description
    h; p; i\
Desctiption:
    # while comment continues, replace // with tab
    : l; n; \_//[^=]_{s_//_\t_;p;};t l;
    # modify the header as footer and print
    x;s_^/_\\_;s_\\$_/_;p
    # also print the non-comment line
    x;p;
  }
  ' input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex matches the whole comment

```
(\/\/=+)(\s*\/\/ .+?$)+
```

Comment: hmm, It doesn't work for me. I'm checking it on this site: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: Correct, had to replace forward slashes, thanks! (ps I have only access to Rubular.com)

Answer (score 0):

A short perl script that should do what you need, explained in comments:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p

$ast = '*' x 75;                  # Number of asterisks.
if (m{//=+}) {                    # Beginning of a comment.
    $inside = 1;
    s{.*}{/$ast\\\nDescription:};
    next;
}
if ($inside) {
    unless (m{^//}) {             # End of a comment.
        undef $inside;
        print '\\', $ast, "/\n" ;
    }
    s{^//}{};                     # Remove the comment sign for internal lines.
}
```

Comment: Yes _Description_ is an additional word. Thanks for answer!

Answer (score 0):

If a regex is still wanted, dont know if there is a better solution or not this is what I came up with:

```
(?<=\/{2}\s)[\w()\.\s]+
```

Should get all the text that is of interest.